# Purely functional soft heap

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, soft-heap

Are there any implementations of a purely functional [soft heap](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2009/SODA09_053_kaplanh.pdf) data structure in any language?

Comment: I got through a bit of it last night; I haven't verified the time complexities, but they seem wrong log( 1/e ) where e is 0<e<1. That'll give a negative complexity. And, they even mention a amortized cost of 0 for some operations. Am I confused on my interpretations? I realize they don't say, O(0), but just 0, I guess in that sense it is a constant, but to switch from O() notation to none, is pretty sloppy.

Comment: Great! Log is only negative for arguments less than 1 but 1/ε is not because 0<ε<1 so 1<ε⁻¹<∞.

Comment: Oh, of course. Yes, you are right. I was clearly (or not I suppose), thinking log(ε). So, when he does say that all operations are amortized cost 0, he is talking about a constant factor?

Comment: I guess amortized cost 0 means constant factor, yes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A quick search of the ACM digital library indicates that Chazelle's soft heap structure, despite being very interesting, has received relatively little study, and that persistent/functional soft heaps are thus an open research topic.

So I would say no, there are no known approaches for persistent soft heaps. Describing one would be a publishable result (it may boil down to adding copying where you would mutate the original structure, and identifying sharing opportunities).

Comment: @Jon, if you plan to tackle this problem, and you haven't read *Purely Functional Data Structures* yet, I suggest you do so. Even though it doesn't cover soft heaps, it will teach you basic principles of functional data structure design that will be helpful in tackling this problem.

Comment: There is a fairly full-featured OCaml implementation of Okasaki's skew-binomial heaps in my Oni CF library: http://bitbucket.org/jhw/oni

Answer (score 1):

The Haim Kaplan, Robert E. Tarjan, Uri Zwick paper describes but doesn't fully analyze purely functional variant. It can be found at:

http://phdtree.org/pdf/44150182-soft-heaps-simplified/

Answer (score 0):

This project has Java code that might not be too terrible to translate to Scala... and then make it more functional.

https://github.com/lowasser/SoftSelect

But as noted previously the Purely Functional Data Structures book has Haskell code that may be easier to adopt to Soft Heaps, especially given the example Java code.

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf

Comment: I am also looking at this paper from the ACM where SoftHeaps are made with binary trees: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1496823